# Why my hashset class works but hashtable fails

Tags: python, hashtable

During these days, I was working on leetcode problems related to hashtable. There are two design questions. One is to design hashSet and the other is to design hashMap. I got some insight from others' code and implemented hashSet design. For hashMap, I think what I should do is to add one extra array to store values but when I submitted my code, it reported wrong answer. I was wondering what's wrong with my code.

Below is my code for HashSet, which passes all test cases.

```
class MyHashSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0
        self.capacity = 8
        self.lf = 2/3
        self.arr = [None] * 8
        
    def hash(self, key):
        return key % self.capacity
    
    def rehash(self, key):
        return (5 * key + 1) % self.capacity
    
    def add(self, key: int) -> None:
        if self.contains(key):
            return 
        if self.size / self.capacity >= self.lf:
            self.capacity <<= 1
            new_arr = [None] * self.capacity
            for i in range(self.capacity >> 1):
                if self.arr[i] and self.arr[i] != "removed":
                    index = self.hash(self.arr[i])
                    while new_arr[index] is not None:
                        index = self.rehash(index)
                    new_arr[index] = self.arr[i]
            self.arr = new_arr
        
        index = self.hash(key)
        while self.arr[index] is not None:
            if self.arr[index] == "removed":
                break
            index = self.rehash(index)
        self.arr[index] = key
        self.size += 1

    def remove(self, key: int) -> None:
        if not self.contains(key):
            return
        index = self.hash(key)
        while self.arr[index] != key:
            index = self.rehash(index)
        self.arr[index] = "removed"
        self.size -= 1

    def contains(self, key: int) -> bool:
        """
        Returns true if this set contains the specified element
        """
        index = self.hash(key)
        while self.arr[index] is not None:
            if self.arr[index] == key:
                return True
            index = self.rehash(index)
        return False
```

Below is my code for my HashMap, which fails on one test case.

```
class MyHashMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0
        self.capacity = 8
        self.lf = 2/3
        self.key_arr = [None] * 8
        self.value_arr = [None] * 8

    def hash(self, key):
        return key % self.capacity
    
    def rehash(self, key):
        return (5 * key + 1) % self.capacity    
        
    def put(self, key: int, value: int) -> None:
        """
        value will always be non-negative.
        """
        contain_flag = False
        if self.contains(key):
            contain_flag = True
        
        if not contain_flag and self.size / self.capacity >= self.lf:
            self.capacity <<= 1
            new_key_arr = [None] * self.capacity
            new_value_arr = [None] * self.capacity
            for i in range(self.capacity >> 1):
                if self.key_arr[i] and self.key_arr[i] != "removed":
                    index = self.hash(self.key_arr[i])
                    while new_key_arr[index] is not None:
                        index = self.rehash(index)
                    new_key_arr[index] = self.key_arr[i]
                    new_value_arr[index] = self.value_arr[i]
            self.key_arr = new_key_arr
            self.value_arr = new_value_arr
            
        index = self.hash(key)
        if contain_flag:
            while self.key_arr[index] != key:
                index = self.rehash(index)
        else:
            while self.key_arr[index] is not None:
                if self.key_arr[index] == "removed":
                    break
                index = self.rehash(index)
        self.key_arr[index] = key
        self.value_arr[index] = value
        self.size += 1

    def get(self, key: int) -> int:
        """
        Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or -1 if this map contains no mapping for the key
        """
        if not self.contains(key):
            return -1
        index = self.hash(key)
        while self.key_arr[index] != key:
            index = self.rehash(index)
        return self.value_arr[index]
        
        

    def remove(self, key: int) -> None:
        """
        Removes the mapping of the specified value key if this map contains a mapping for the key
        """
        if not self.contains(key):
            return
        index = self.hash(key)
        while self.key_arr[index] != key:
            index = self.rehash(index)
        self.key_arr[index] = "removed"
        self.value_arr[index] = "removed"
        self.size -= 1
        
    def contains(self, key):
        index = self.hash(key)
        while self.key_arr[index] is not None:
            if self.key_arr[index] == key:
                return True
            index = self.rehash(index)
        return False
```

Later, I found if I initialized hashMap's size from 8 to 1024, it can pass all test cases but I am not able to figure out why it behaves like that.

Comment: What test case fails? Have you debugged it to try to pinpoint the problem? Please create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem. You can probably omit the working class from the question, we don't really need to see that.

Comment: It is one leetcode problem and I failed at the second last test case which contains 1001 operations. And from the test result, I found that I only failed at the 691st operation. In this case, I am not able to create a minimal reproducible example. Thanks for your help

Comment: You could try fuzz testing to reproduce a failure.  Use python's built in dictionary as a reference/oracle implementation, and do random things to both your map and the inbuilt one until they diverge in content.  Have them log the operations so you can understand how the failure happened.  This is the life of a programmer....

Comment: @Tony Delroy Thanks for your advice , I will try